# Why I'm getting error like this while printing today's date in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

This is my imported libraries and code_

```
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

exp_list = data['records']['expiryDates']
exp_date = exp_list[1]
exp_date = datetime.strptime(exp_date, "%d %b %Y") # Convert the type date object into datetime format
today = datetime.date.today() #Today's date
delta = exp_date - today
print(delta.days)
```

When I trying to run this code I'm getting error like this_

```
      39 print(exp_date)
      40 
 ---> 41 today = datetime.date.today() #Today's date
      42 delta = exp_date - today
      43 print(delta.days)

      AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'
```

Comment: Remove the  `from datetime import datetime`.    Then replace `datetime.strptime` with `datetime.datetime.strptime`

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the error output, and is incomplete. In other words it's not a proper [mre]. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: datetime doesn't have date. "import datetime" then run "datetime.date.today()".

Comment: Alternatively, you can remove `import datetime` and instead modify `from datetime import datetime` to `from datetime import datetime, date`.  Then you'd replace `datetime.date` with just `date`

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use `datetime.date.today()`, just import the built-in `datetime` module .E.g

```py
import datetime
datetime.date.today()
# datetime.date(2022, 5, 16)
```

or, you can use

```py
from datetime import date
date.today()
# datetime.date(2022, 5, 16)
```

Comment: Hi Rojan, I've made a slight edit to your answer to improve the legibility of your code. You can enclose code blocks in triple backticks and the name of the language (i.e. `\`\`\`python3 #somecode \`\`\``) so that the code is highlighted properly. See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today() #Today's date
print('today: ', today)
exp_date = datetime.strptime('2022-05-30',"%Y-%m-%d")
print('exp_date: ', exp_date)
diff = exp_date-today
print('diff: ', diff)


>> today:  2022-05-17 08:50:09.706947
>> exp_date:  2022-05-30 00:00:00
>> diff:  12 days, 15:09:50.293053
```

Comment: Kindly add enough details so that future readers can understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today() # 16 May 2022
exp_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 9, 56) # 28 May 2022
delta = exp_date - today

print(delta.days) #12
```